# Geometric distribution: the probability of winning in fewer than 3 attempts

Tags: probability

I have a seemingly simple problem but I can't find the one solution listed among the possible solutions:

> We have a heads or tails game with probability to win equals to $0.2$ (heads) at each play.
>   Every play is independent.
>   If the player wins, he stops.
>   If the player looses, he continues.
>   What is the probability that he wins in less than 3 plays ?

P(he wins in less than 3 plays) = P(he wins at the first play) + P(he wins at the second play)
$$= P(H) + P(TH) = 0.2 + 0.8\cdot 0.2 = 0.36$$

But I cannot see that $0.36$ in the listed possible.

Another way to look at it:

P(he wins in less than 3 plays) $= 1 - P(X > 2) = 1 - 0.8\cdot 0.8 = 0.36$

The only listed solution that looks plausible to me is $0,488$, but it would equals to:
$1 - 0.8*0.8*0.8$, which looks **dead wrong**.

Can you please confirm ?

The offered solutions are: 0.2 ; 0,384 ; 0,60 ; 0,008 and 0,488

Comment: The expression $1-0.8^3$ is the probability of winning in at most 3 plays (including the 3rd play).

Comment: Yes, so it is not the correct solution. Do you agree on my solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall understand the question as "in less (or equal) than 3 plays"

Comment: In the exam question, this was not written in less or equals but only in less than.

Comment: what are the possible answers ?

Comment: Possible solutions: 0.2 ; 0,384 ; 0,60 ; 0,008 and 0,488

Comment: Definitely, the question was implying "at most 3 games".

Comment: Maybe but poorly phrased, what would you have done ?